# remote user name

Tags: php

Is it possible to get remote username when I get a referral link without involving any server side code from the referral link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean like if I clicked a link to your site on Stack Overflow, you would want to be able to see that my username is "Agent Conundrum"? No, you can't do that without the help of the referring site. The only information you should be able to get is the (permanently misspelled) `HTTP_REFERER` in the `$_SERVER` superglobal array, which tells you the page the user came from. Even then, there are ways to [block or change](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/modify-headers/) this so you shouldn't count on it being set (especially since it wouldn't be set if the user navigated directly to your page via the address bar).

Frankly, I wouldn't want to use a site that leaked personal information (and for some sites, even the username qualifies as personal information), and I wouldn't want to use a site that tries to harvest such leaked information without my knowledge.

Generally, any site where you have a legitimate reason to broadcast this information would have some sort of API built in, like FacebookConnect. Even then, it should be strictly opt-in for the user.

Comment: @Illusionist If I've solved your problem, please consider accepting my answer. Also, I've made a couple edits since your comment (one of which was made during the editing window so SO doesn't mark it as an edit), so please be sure to reread my answer to get the additions.

Answer (score 1):

As a general thing: no. The HTTP protocol does not involve the transmission of a remote user name.

Answer (score 0):

Hey, it could help to answer if you would be a little more [specific](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#beprecise) on which kind of service are you trying to fetch the data from.

Large/Public services tend to have somekind of an accessible API that you can fork on your referrer, but other than that its mostly that you need to regexp the site and know the structure of the HTML pretty much.